# how to run a test using pytest

Tags: terminal, pytest, python-3.8

I typed "pytest" in the terminal, and then I received an error. I have a feeling that there might be something wrong with my directory.

Here's the screenshot:

[image]

I tried:

1. `export PATH=$PATH:/Users/***/Library/Python/3.8/bin`
2. `sudo pytest`
3. `pip uninstall pytest` and then `pip install pytest`

However, none of them fixed the error.

I am using Python 3.8.5